# Overlapping Marker Spiderfier for Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to know is there any library exist for Google Map which expand all markers which are on the same LatLng.Like this : http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo.html
This library exist for JavaScript but i didnt find any way or library to achieve this functionality.If anyone know the answer please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to find the Overlapping Marker Spiderfier feature for Android as well.

I came across a GitHub project that attempts this at:

https://github.com/Gid-CTO/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-java

I have yet to try it out for myself. If anyone knows of anything else or have used this successfully, please let me know.

EDIT: I have officially tried the Overlapping Marker Spiderfier for Android by Iliya Romm (the GitHub project) and got it to work successfully. I had some trouble in the beginning but posted it as an issue on GitHub and the author was more than helpful. The instructions are incomplete and there's some additional code you need to add. You can see the additional code here: https://github.com/Gid-CTO/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-java/issues/2

You can use it in combination with the marker clustering tool that is part of the Android-Maps-Extensions library.